# C++ pointing to array in another function

Tags: c++, arrays

I've got Function1 where user inputs data in `array1`. I must make `array2` in Function2 to be equal to array1 from Function1.

How do I "tell it" that it should use `array1` from Function1?

I've tried

```
array2[50] = array1[50];
```

but of course that is not working.

Comment: I would suggest this -> http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/13291

Comment: What is your goal ? Do you only need the values of array1 to be read by Function2 ? do you need to modify them ? Did you consider using something like a vector instead of an array ?

Comment: Do you really ned to *copy* the array? Why not just use *the same* array?

Comment: I needed to copy the array and modify the copy. I have yet to study how vectors work, so I have no idea how to use them. Thanks though.

Comment: Vectors work like "smart arrays". Besides automatic resizing and bounds checking, you can simply do vector2=vector1 and vector2 will be an independant copy of vector 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to copy `array1` elementwise into `array2`, e.g.

```
for (unsigned i=0; i<array1_size; ++i) {
    array2[i] = array1[i];
}
```

You can also use `std::copy` from the `algorithm` header.

```
std::copy(array1, array1 + array1_size, array2);
```

For both approaches you need to know the number of elements in `array1` (`array1_size` in the examples). Also, `array2` needs to be at least as big as `array1`.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over all elements in one array and assign them to the second one.

Answer (score -1):

memcpy(second_array, first_array, sizeof(second_array));

[Original Source Site][http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/13291]

Comment: Depending on what his arrays contain this can be problematic since it doesn't invoke copy constructors but copies raw memory.

Comment: Well there is no indicator in the question that shows that there are pointers to structures or objects, in addition there is no hint that a shallow or deep copy is needed, if he only has int's or chars in the table the application will me enormously fast compared to std::copy, i claim that more than 90% of all realtime systems use those low level mechanisms to copy arrays and even single objects

Comment: Did you benchmark this? With my compiler and int arrays `std::copy` is as fast as `memcpy` but much safer.

Comment: This can depend on your platform/compiler , std::copy uses memmove which is not as fast as memcpy because it containts extra checks, i have no system here to properly make performance tests, if you make 1000 memcpy's vs 1000 memoves you will already see the difference, adding the std::copy's check will decrease performance again